# Sort an array so that a given value would be the first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort the array so that if a given value `($first_in_array) = 'brand'` value, the array would become the first it the queue. In the given example an array with `index[1]` should appear like at `index[0]`.

```
$first_in_array = 'PickMeFirst';

$data = Array(
    0 => array(
        'articleId'     => 5478,
        'articleName'   => 'Demo artcle name 1',
        'brand'         => 'Unbranded',
       ),
    1 => array(
        'articleId'     => 8785,
        'articleName'   => 'Demo artcle name 2',
        'brand'         => 'PickMeFirst',
       ),
    2 => array(
        'articleId'     => 1258,
        'articleName'   => 'Demo artcle name 3',
        'brand'         => 'None',
       ),
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: Look for `usort` examples. All you need to do is say that when the brand matches, that element should come before the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function of `usort` and first deal with the case where exactly one of the two matches that specific string. In all other cases use the normal `strcmp` result:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($first_in_array)  {
    return ($b["brand"] === $first_in_array) - ($a["brand"] === $first_in_array)
        ?: strcmp($a["brand"], $b["brand"]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer moves your value to the first position. However, it also moves other values. Which is absolutely fine, if that is not a concern for you. You could also do the following, which will move your value to the front, but leave other values in place.

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($first_in_array) {
    if($b['brand'] === $first_in_array) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not a problem in my case at the moment, but might me useful later on. I highly appreciate your addition to the solution.

Comment: Bear in mind that `strcmp` is case sensitive also. You can look into `strcasecmp` for a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: Why not just test for `$b['brand'] === $first_in_array` instead of using `strcmp`?

Comment: @Jeto no good reason that I can see, thank you for bringing that to my attention.